# solver_get_unsat_core() in ML (OCaml) API returns empty core

Tags: ocaml, z3

I am trying to write a simple Z3 problem using the OCaml API to extract an unsat core. The problem is that the unsat core returned is empty when it should not be. Do you have any ideas or can you point out what I might be doing wrong?

I am following the example in Rise4fun only using the OCaml API:

```
let _ =
  (* make a new context:
    * - enable model construction
    * - enable quantifier instantiation
  *)
  let ctx = Z3.mk_context [("MODEL","true"); ("PROOF_MODE", "2"); ("MBQI","true")] in

  (* make a new "default" solver *)
  let solver = Z3.mk_solver ctx in

  (* assert some stupid constraints: exists x: int, y: int.  x < y *)
  let x_symb = Z3.mk_string_symbol ctx "x" in
  let x = Z3.mk_const ctx x_symb (Z3.mk_bool_sort ctx) in

  let y_symb = Z3.mk_string_symbol ctx "y" in
  let y = Z3.mk_const ctx y_symb (Z3.mk_bool_sort ctx) in

  let z_symb = Z3.mk_string_symbol ctx "z" in
  let z = Z3.mk_const ctx z_symb (Z3.mk_bool_sort ctx) in

  let p1_symb = Z3.mk_string_symbol ctx "p1" in
  let p1 = Z3.mk_const ctx p1_symb (Z3.mk_bool_sort ctx) in

  let p2_symb = Z3.mk_string_symbol ctx "p2" in
  let p2 = Z3.mk_const ctx p2_symb (Z3.mk_bool_sort ctx) in

  let p3_symb = Z3.mk_string_symbol ctx "p3" in
  let p3 = Z3.mk_const ctx p3_symb (Z3.mk_bool_sort ctx) in

  let p4_symb = Z3.mk_string_symbol ctx "p4" in
  let p4 = Z3.mk_const ctx p4_symb (Z3.mk_bool_sort ctx) in

  let p5_symb = Z3.mk_string_symbol ctx "p5" in
  let p5 = Z3.mk_const ctx p5_symb (Z3.mk_bool_sort ctx) in

  let p6_symb = Z3.mk_string_symbol ctx "p6" in
  let p6 = Z3.mk_const ctx p6_symb (Z3.mk_bool_sort ctx) in

  (* assert implications *)
  let notx = Z3.mk_not ctx x in
  let noty = Z3.mk_not ctx y in
  let notz = Z3.mk_not ctx z in
  let implies1 = Z3.mk_implies ctx p1 (Z3.mk_or ctx [| x; y|]) in
  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver implies1;

  let implies2 = Z3.mk_implies ctx p2 (Z3.mk_or ctx [| notx; y|]) in
  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver implies2;

  let implies3 = Z3.mk_implies ctx p3 (Z3.mk_or ctx [| x; noty|]) in
  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver implies3;

  let implies4 = Z3.mk_implies ctx p4 (Z3.mk_or ctx [| notx; noty|]) in
  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver implies4;

  let implies5 = Z3.mk_implies ctx p5 (Z3.mk_or ctx [| y; z|]) in
  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver implies5;

  let implies6 = Z3.mk_implies ctx p6 (Z3.mk_or ctx [| y; notz|]) in
  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver implies6;

  (* assert some constraints over p1, ..., p6 *)
  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver p1;
  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver p2;
  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver p3;
  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver p4;
  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver p5;
  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver p6;

  (* check satisfiability *)
  match Z3.solver_check ctx solver with
  | Z3.L_TRUE -> (* SAT *)
      (* get model *)
      let mdl = Z3.solver_get_model ctx solver in
      print_endline "Sat";
      print_endline (Z3.model_to_string ctx mdl)

  | Z3.L_FALSE -> (* UNSAT *)
    let unsat_core = Z3.solver_get_unsat_core ctx solver in
    print_endline "Unsat";
    print_endline "Solver";
    print_endline (Z3.solver_to_string ctx solver);
    print_endline "Unsat Core";
    print_endline (Z3.ast_vector_to_string ctx unsat_core)

  | Z3.L_UNDEF -> (* shrug *)
      print_endline "Unknown"
```

The generated output is:

```
Unsat
Solver
(solver
  (=> p1 (or x y))
  (=> p2 (or (not x) y))
  (=> p3 (or x (not y)))
  (=> p4 (or (not x) (not y)))
  (=> p5 (or y z))
  (=> p6 (or y (not z)))
  p1
  p2
  p3
  p4
  p5
  p6)
Unsat Core
(ast-vector)
```

Explicit check on the size of the unsat_core ast_vector returns 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to restate my question: Does anyone know how to enable UNSAT_CORE support using the OCaml API: either as a context configuration parameter or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me if I use `Z3.solver_check_assumptions` instead of just `Z3.solver_check`.  To use this, use introduce new boolean variables for each assertion and then you add those boolean variables as assumptions.  For example, I added the variables `as1` and `as2` as my assumptions.  Running this example, I get a result of:

```
Unsat
as1
as2
```

Here is the example code:

```
let _ =
  (* make a new context:
    * - enable model construction
  *)
  let ctx = Z3.mk_context [("MODEL","true")] in

  (* make a new "default" solver *)
  let solver = Z3.mk_solver ctx in

  (* assert some stupid constraints: exists x: int, y: int.  x < y *)
  let x_symb = Z3.mk_string_symbol ctx "x" in
  let x = Z3.mk_const ctx x_symb (Z3.mk_int_sort ctx) in

  let y_symb = Z3.mk_string_symbol ctx "y" in
  let y = Z3.mk_const ctx y_symb (Z3.mk_int_sort ctx) in

  let as1_symb = Z3.mk_string_symbol ctx "as1" in
  let as1 = Z3.mk_const ctx as1_symb (Z3.mk_bool_sort ctx) in
  let as2_symb = Z3.mk_string_symbol ctx "as2" in
  let as2 = Z3.mk_const ctx as2_symb (Z3.mk_bool_sort ctx) in

  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver (Z3.mk_iff ctx as1 (Z3.mk_lt ctx x y));
  Z3.solver_assert ctx solver (Z3.mk_iff ctx as2 (Z3.mk_lt ctx y x));

  (* check satisfiability *)
  match Z3.solver_check_assumptions ctx solver [| as1; as2 |] with
  | Z3.L_TRUE -> (* SAT *)
      (* get model *)
      let mdl = Z3.solver_get_model ctx solver in
      print_endline "Sat";
      print_endline (Z3.model_to_string ctx mdl)

  | Z3.L_FALSE -> (* UNSAT *)
      print_endline "Unsat";
      let core = Z3.solver_get_unsat_core ctx solver in
      for i = 0 to (Z3.ast_vector_size ctx core) - 1 do
        print_endline (Z3.ast_to_string ctx (Z3.ast_vector_get ctx core i))
      done

  | Z3.L_UNDEF -> (* shrug *)
      print_endline "Unknown"
```

Comment: Wonderful! This is exactly what I was going for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `("UNSAT_CORE","true");` just like you set `("MODEL","true");`.

Comment: I spent a significant chunk of time trying to find documentation on the names of these configuration parameters. If anyone knows of a place that lists or describes these please let me know.

I have tried the strings: "UNSAT_CORE", "UNSAT_CORES", "PRODUCE_UNSAT_CORES", "M_CORES" and a few other likely suspects. None of these seem to be recognized by the mk_context() function. Upon execution there is a warning: `WARNING: Error setting UNSAT_CORE, unknown option.`

Comment: I have been looking at all other APIs for a sign of what this parameter name should be but I cannot find a reference. I have tried updating the parameter using the update_param_value() but that just causes a runtime error and program termination: `Error setting 'UNSAT_CORE', reason: unknown option.
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
Abort trap: 6`
Additionally, "UNSAT_CORE" like "MODEL" (but unlike "MBQI") is not stored as a solver parameter since solver_get_param_descr() returns a set of parameters that does not include these.

Comment: "DISPLAY_UNSAT_CORE" doesn't do it either.